# Remove header from multiple csv files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have multiple `csv` files coming on daily basis from a different server. These files are huge(over 200 MB). I have to remove header for all these `csv` files 
and replace them with required column headers using batch file.

The below code works fine to remove the column headers from one single file only:

```
@echo off
set "csv=mycsv.csv">"%csv%.new"
(
    for /f skip^=1^ usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%A in ("%csv%") do echo %%A
)
move /y "%csv%.new" "%csv%" >nul
```

Comment: This will be far, far, easier if you use PowerShell instead of trying to do this in cmd shell script (batch).

Comment: Your code only removes the header line. It does not replace the header with new values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the CSV files do not contain any <kbd>TAB</kbd> characters (which were replaced by sequences of <kbd>SPACE</kbd> characters by the used `more` command) and that no file is longer than 65534 lines (in which case `more` expects user interaction), you could try one of the following:

1. The new column header is given by another file `headerfile.csv`:

   ```
   < "headerfile.csv" set /P "HEADER="
   for %%F in ("*.csv") do (
       if /I not "%%~F"=="headerfile.csv" (
           > "%%~F.tmp" echo(%HEADER%
           >>"%%~F.tmp" more +1 "%%~F"
           move /Y "%%~F.tmp" "%%~F"
       )
   )
   ```

   You might not want to exclude `headerfile.csv` from being processed in case it is not located in the current directory where all the other CSV files are; simply remove the `if` query then.
2. The new column header is given as a string constant:

   ```
   set "HEADER=new,header,string,here"
   for %%F in ("*.csv") do (
       > "%%~F.tmp" echo(%HEADER%
       >>"%%~F.tmp" more +1 "%%~F"
       move /Y "%%~F.tmp" "%%~F"
   )
   ```

---

#### Update

Here is a way without using the `more` command, so its limitations do no longer apply. It does also not use `for /F` which would limit the length of each line to 8191 bytes/characters:

1. The new column header is given by another file `headerfile.csv`:

   ```
   < "headerfile.csv" set /P "HEADER="
   for %%F in ("*.csv") do (
       if /I not "%%~F"=="headerfile.csv" (
           > "%%~F.tmp" echo(%HEADER%
           >>"%%~F.tmp" < "%%~F" (set /P = & findstr "^")
           move /Y "%%~F.tmp" "%%~F"
       )
   )
   ```
2. The new column header is given as a string constant:

   ```
   set "HEADER=new,header,string,here"
   for %%F in ("*.csv") do (
       > "%%~F.tmp" echo(%HEADER%
       >>"%%~F.tmp" < "%%~F" (set /P = & findstr "^")
       move /Y "%%~F.tmp" "%%~F"
   )
   ```

Note that the header line is still limited to 8191 bytes/characters, because it is stored in a variable (in order to avoid multiple file read operations), and also by the related `echo(%HEADER%` command line which is also limited to that size. To overcome this limit, place only the header into a text file and with in the loop, copy it to `%%~F.tmp` prior to appending the data.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This code works for only one file and it doesn't seem to remove the old column headers, though it 
does add the new one.Let me try to explain my requirement. I have two files in a folder file1.csv and file2.csv that contain the data.  

file1.csv with column names _name_ and _sal_ and file2.csv with the same column names _name_ and _sal_.
required header columns are present in headerfile.csv in the same folder and the column names are _ename_ and _esal_.

My requirement is to replace headers in file1 and file2 with headers from headerfile.

Comment: I specified `for %%F` but used the reference `%%A` later, sorry for that -- I fixed it, see my [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40929311/2)...

Comment: More will pause if the file has more than 65534 lines.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I totally forgot about that, I'll include it in my answer... so there seems to be no reliable way to do that with pure batch scripting as `for /F` limits the line lengths to 8190...

Comment: @Squashman, I found a way without using `for /F` -- see my updated answer (in a couple of minutes)...

Comment: Thank you for the extra help. But there are still problems with the updated script. For some reason this was deleting all rows. Can you help me 
with the script for tab-delimited csv files.

Comment: @chandu, what are TAB-delimited **C**SV files?? Anyway, the script does not care about any delimiters nor the content of the files at all as long as they are (ANSI-encoded) text files; so are you sure you copied the script correctly and adapted the file paths properly?

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (*.csv) do echo %%a>csv.new&goto mainbody
:mainbody
for /f "skip=1delims=" %%a in (*.csv) do echo %%a>>csv.new
```

should do what you want, using the ubiquitous crystal ball to scry "required column headers" to mean "the column headers from a .csv file"

Comment: Thanks Magoo for your response. The required headers are indeed being taken from .csv file. I tried with the code you have suggested but for some reason it
doesn't seem to have worked for me. I don't see an error message either.

Answer (score 0):

You may even get away with using MORE:

```bat
For %%A In (*.csv) Do More +1 "%%A" 1>%%~nA.new
```

***Note*** - This method will convert any tabs to spaces

Comment: More will pause if the file has more than 65534 lines.

Comment: So will I and that's about Excel's limit too isn't it so it's not really an issue for me.